# .htaccess image to web page redirect?

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a .htaccess script I can use to redirect the url of an image to an actual web page?

What can I do to make it so when someone accesses an image via their address bar by typing in: http://www.sitename.com/images/1.jpg

It will instead redirect the user to the web page:
http://www.sitename.com/view/1.html

I want to still be able to place the images in image tags though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^https?:\\www\.yourdomain\.com
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  (.*)\.jpg$
RewriteRule images/(\d+)\.jpg    http://www.yourdomain.com/view/$1.html   [L,R=301]
```

by using this you can put images in img tag and it will work but If you try to access them directly , it will redirect to html file.
Note: If you want others have permission to use your images use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^$
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you can help me here now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677663/htaccess-image-to-web-page-redirect