# .htaccess image to web page redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Is there a .htaccess script I can use to redirect the url of an image to an actual web page?

What can I do to make it so when someone accesses an image via their address bar by typing in: http://www.sitename.com/uploads/192-file-name-here.jpg
or other extensions like
http://www.sitename.com/uploads/235-file-name-here.png

It will instead redirect the user to the web page:
http://www.sitename.com/view/192-file-name-here/

I want to still be able to place the images in image tags across the site and on external sites though.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?:\\www\.sitename\.com
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.jpg$
RewriteRule images/(\d+)\.jpg  http://www.sitename.com/view/$1.html   [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
```

Can this be modified/re-written to perform my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in your `.htaccess`, it will redirect all requests that are sent directly by user.
**Note**: Other sites,as you mentioned can put your images in their pages.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/uploads/(\d+)-(.+)\.(png|gif|jpe?g|bmp)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.sitename.com/view/%1-%2/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can always redirect images to a webpage or anything using `.htaccess`.
But `images/(\d+).*\.jpg` may be better.

Comment: Okay. I'm trying to modify the current script to work with my site, what would I need to modify?

Comment: @Aaron I don't know, understanding what u need to accomplish maybe?