# Can't get my .htaccess redirect working. (home.co.za/images/example.gif to home.html)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I know similar questions has been asked here a number of times but I simply don't have the know-how to extrapolate a solution to my issue from that. It goes without saying that any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to redirect anyone from http://itrace.co.za/images/example.gif

to the home page: http://itrace.co.za

Here is what I have so far but nothing happens. Iv'e tried other scripts but i usually get an error.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/upload/(\d+)-(.+)\.(png|gif|jpe?g|bmp)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://itrace.co.za/%1-%2/
```

That code is from another post here: [.htaccess image to web page redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677663/htaccess-image-to-web-page-redirect)

Please help, it's likely so simple for you experts :)

Comment: Your original URI doesn't start with `/upload/`. Do you want to redirect everything under `/images/` to be redirected to home page?

Comment: Yeah that would be ideal i think

Comment: But that example.gif image is the essential one to be redirected to the homepage

Comment: I don't clear undestand what you want but %1... take matches only from the **last** RewriteCond. So at least swap 1st and 2nd lines

Comment: If you want to redirect **all**  from upload then change `(\d+)-(.+)\.(png|gif|jpe?g|bmp)` to `(.+)`

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/upload/(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  http://itrace.co.za/%1-%2/

still nothing

Comment: I'm very appreciative of all your help fellows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/images/.+$ http://itrace.co.za/
```